# Fancybox with dynamically loaded images and number of images

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, xml-rpc

I'm using **fancybox** js and css to make the image slider. In that slider I want to change the number of images and src of images dynamically, but I didn't get any idea for that.

Code:

```
$("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function () {
    alert("clicked");
    $.fancybox.open([
        {
            href: 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
            title: 'this image links to bbc news'
        }, {
            href: 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',
            title: 'this image links to jquery'
        }, {
            href: 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg',
            title: 'this image links to fancybox'
        }
    ], {
        nextEffect: 'fade',
        prevEffect: 'fade',
        loop: false,
        mouseWheel: true,
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic',
        openOpacity: true,
        closeOpacity: true,
        cyclic: false
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use fancy box 1.3 or 2?

1. In general first of all it would be good to know what you mean by dynamically. On which event you want to change the images?
   i. e. when user clicks something or in certain time intervals
2. From where do you want to get the new image sets? Load them by ajax or are they already embedded in the page somewhere?

I sometimes do it like this:

```
<a class="mylink" href="#firstset">link</a>
<a class="mylink" href="#secondset">link</a>  

    <div class="content" style="display:none">
      <div id="firstset">
        image...
      </div>
      <div id="secondset">
        image...
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(".mylink").click(function() {
    var $content = $($(this).attr('href')).clone();

    $.fancybox({
      'titlePosition': 'inside', 'padding': '0', 'titleShow': false,
      'content': $content,
      'onComplete': function () {
        init your slider

      }
    });
    return false;
})
```

this is just to give you an idea and one of many possible solutions
specify more exact than you can get a better answer

Comment: thanks for your help..Then with help of xmlrpc method i get the images from server and store that images into a corresponding pages with help of javascript and xmlrpc...so the number of images to slide may be different for every products..so i want to know how to change that number of images when page loads using javascript? then for a information we are developing a iphone web application with help of phonegap and xmlrpc.

Comment: den i have one doubt also..that is finally you said init the slider in script..i don't know how to init that slider

Comment: den i dont know what all the things to add inside that firstset and secondset..can you sent any referred url page